# Graphing the basic sine and cosine curves.

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions

1. Draw $x$ and $y$ axes, marking the $x$ axis with tick marks that are a multiple of $\pi$ and the $y$ axis with integers to fit the problem.
2. Determine all $x$-intercepts by solving an equation such as $x = \sin^{-1} 0$ or $x = \cos^{-1} 0$ for all $x$-values in the interval you're graphing.
3. Graph the intercepts.
4. Determine the $y$-intercept by letting $x = 0$ and solving for $y$ in the equation.
5. Graph the $y$-intercept.
6. Determine where the extreme values are by solving an equation such as $x = \sin^{-1} \pm 1$ or $x = \cos^{-1} \pm 1$ for all $x$-values in the interval you're graphing.
7. Graph those values.
8. Sketch in the curve.

Example problem:

Graph $y = \sin x$ between $x = 2\pi$ and $x = 4\pi$.

A. To find the $x$-intercepts, solve $x = \sin^{-1} 0$ to get $x = 2\pi$ or $3\pi$ or $4\pi$. There's no $y$-intercept here, because the $y$-axis isn't in that interval. The function is equal to $1$ at $x = \frac {5\pi}{2}$ and $-1$ at $x = \frac {7\pi}{2}$. The graph is shown in the figure.

My questions are this:

1. How does one come up with $2\pi$ or $3\pi$ or $4\pi$ from $x = \sin^{-1} 0$? As the equation equals $0$ and only computes between $1$ and $-1$.
2. I'm having trouble on how to compute the $y$-intercept. I'm going to say you just solve $y = \sin x$? In this case plug in $2\pi$ or $3\pi$ or $4\pi$?In the answer it says "there's no $y$-intercept here, because the $y$-axis isn't in that interval".  Do they mean the range of $2\pi$ to $4\pi$, when they say interval?
3. Number $6$ in the $8$ points up top. When I determine extreme values do I just solve $y = \sin x$ and then plug the values into $x = \sin^{-1} \pm 1$ or $x = \cos^{-1} \pm 1$?

Comment: When you enter the values into your calculator, make sure it is in radian mode.

Comment: Blah.... simple mistake.

Comment: 1): It comes from the general solution for $\sin x = 0 \ , \ (n\pi, n \in \mathbb{Z})$. 2) : you need to solve $y = \sin x$ when x = 0.

Comment: For extremes you need to find the solution to $\pm 1 = \sin x$ and likewise for cos. Hopefully you know how to solve trignometry equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use the definition that the sine of an angle in standard position (vertex at the origin, initial side on the positive $x$-axis) is the $y$-coordinate of the point where the terminal side of the angle intersects the unit circle.  [image: unit_circle_definitions_for_sine_and_cosine]

Therefore, the graph of the sine function $f(x) = \sin x$ is obtained by tracing out the $y$-coordinates of the point where the terminal side of the angle intersects the unit circle as it is rotated around the circle.

[image: graph_of_sine_function_is_obtained_by_tracing_out_y-coordinates_of_points_where_the_terminal_side_of_the_angle_intersects_the_unit_circle]

Once a full revolution of the circle is completed, continuing to rotate the terminal side of the angle around the circle causes the values to repeat.  Hence, the sine function is [periodic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_function).  Since there are $2\pi$ radians in a full circle, 
$$f(x + 2\pi) = \sin(x + 2\pi) = \sin x = f(x)$$
Since there is no smaller positive value $p$ such that $f(x + p) = f(x)$ for each $p$ in its domain, the sine function has period $2\pi$.

[image: sine_function_graph]

You were asked to restrict the domain of the function to the interval $[2\pi, 4\pi]$, which yields the graph shown below.

[image: restricted_sine_function_graph]

Let's call the function in your example $g$.  Then $g: [2\pi, 4\pi] \to [-1, 1]$ is the function defined by $g(x) = \sin x$.

Since $0$ is not in the domain of $g$, it does not have a $y$-intercept.

The sine function $f(x) = \sin x$ has an $x$-intercept at each point where the terminal side of the angle lies on the $x$-axis, which occurs when $x = n\pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}$.  The three values where this occurs in the domain of $g$ are $2\pi$, $3\pi$, and $4\pi$.

The sine function $f(x) = \sin x$ reaches its maximum value of $1$ whenever the terminal side of the angle lies on the positive $y$-axis, which occurs when 
\begin{align*}
x & = \arcsin (1) + 2n\pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}\\ 
  & = \frac{\pi}{2} + 2n\pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}
\end{align*}
where the $2n\pi$ term is used to account for the periodicity of the sine function as all angles that differ by an integer multiple of $2\pi$ have the same sine value.  The only such value in the domain of $g$ is 
$$\frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi = \frac{5\pi}{2}$$

The sine function $f(x) = x$ reaches its minimum value of $-1$ whenever the terminal side of the angle lies on the negative $y$-axis, which occurs when
\begin{align*}
x & = \arcsin(-1) + 2n\pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}\\
  & = -\frac{\pi}{2} + 2n\pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}
\end{align*}
The only such value in the domain of $g$ is
$$x = -\frac{\pi}{2} + 4\pi = \frac{7\pi}{2}$$
Again, the $2n\pi$ term is used to account for the periodicity of the sine function.

I have addressed your second and third questions above.  As for your first question, note that the inverse sine function $h: [-1, 1] \to [-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}]$, denoted by $h(x) = \arcsin x$, is defined by 
$$\arcsin x = y \iff \sin y = x, -\frac{\pi}{2} \leq y \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$$

[image: arcsine_function_graph]

Since $0$ is the only angle in the interval $[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}]$ with sine equal to zero, $\arcsin(0) = 0$.  Since the sine function has period $2\pi$, knowing that the arcsine of zero is equal to zero tells you that $g$ will have $x$-intercepts at $2\pi$ and $4\pi$.  It does not tell you that $g$ also has a zero at $3\pi$.  For that value, you can use the observation made above that the sine function is equal to zero when the terminal side of the angle lies on the $x$-axis.

Comment: What do you mean by $n$? Could you explain $\mathbb{Z}$? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you mean nth?

Comment: @WilliamZlacki  The set $\mathbb{Z}$ is the set of integers.  $$\mathbb{Z} = \{\ldots, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots\}$$  The notation $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ means $n$ is an integer.  The reason I am adding integer multiples of $2\pi$ to the solution of an equation is that coterminal angles (angles with the same terminal side) have the same sine.

Comment: Exactly, what I figured.

Comment: I've finally figured out what to put into the calculator(hopefully I'm right). Either $1, 0, -1$, but how do I know what one?

Comment: You have not said what you are trying to find when you plug those numbers into the calculator.

Comment: Pretty much got it.

Answer (score 1):

Inverse functions are expressed in radians and degrees. When using a graphics calculator you should choose the proper button... radin/degree selector.

You should be clear that  input or argument is ($x$), and result/output is $y$.

Comment: Blah... simple mistake.

Comment: What about questions $1$, $2$, and $4$?

Comment: Decde first  whether you want to sketch sin graph or cos graph. These are two quite different plots. The repeating period on x axis same  for both. Patiently go point by point for x and find corresponding y in each case, but one after another.